# Insert image doesn't pickup right size

Tags: images

I have a very annoying problem.

I have created some custom sizes in my media gallery using "simple image size" plugin, but the issue is not related to it as it happens also with wp native media sizes.

Basically, when I upload an image and I then go and select a size, the size i select doesn't reflect the actual size... well, an image can explain it better.

[image: Check it out].

So, as you can see I have created a number of image sizes, and in my case both "ninesixty" and "grande" are 960px wide, but I am seeing only 625... why is that?

This is driving me crazy, any help is most welcome!!

Comment: what are the pixel dimensions of the original image you uploaded?

Comment: 1920 wide and around 1000 hi